# How to communicating with web services from BrightScript inside task node?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm new to Roku-tv app development. I have a problem with my application when communicating with web services from BrightScript. I'm struggling to understand how working Task node threads in BrightScript. It's hard to find relative resources about Brightscript language. Here is my project structure.

[image]

I need to get API data into the `welcome_screen.xml`. I found a GitHub repo called [roku-fetch](https://github.com/briandunnington/roku-fetch). using that fetch implantation I tried to call API. It's working on `Main.brs` in the source folder. How can I call it in `welcome_screen.brs` and get data into `welcome_screen.xml`

welcome_screen.brs

```
function init()

    m.top.setFocus(true)
    m.background = m.top.findNode("background")
    m.background.uri = "pkg:/images/welcome.png"

    m.firstLabel = m.top.findNode("firstLabel")
    m.firstLabel.font.size = 19
    m.firstLabel.color = "#ffffff"
    m.firstLabel.font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf"

    m.secondLabel = m.top.findNode("secondLabel")
    m.secondLabel.font.size = 25
    m.secondLabel.color = "#F2CD33"
    m.secondLabel.font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf"

    m.thirdLabel = m.top.findNode("thirdLabel")
    m.thirdLabel.font.size = 19
    m.thirdLabel.color = "#ffffff"
    m.thirdLabel.font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/Inter-SemiBold.ttf"
    m.thirdLabel.lineSpacing = 2

    m.fourthLabel = m.top.findNode("fourthLabel")
    m.fourthLabel.font.size = 12
    m.fourthLabel.color = "#F2CD33"
    m.fourthLabel.font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf"

    m.fifthLabel = m.top.findNode("fifthLabel")
    m.fifthLabel.font.size = 12
    m.fifthLabel.color = "#F2CD33"
    m.fifthLabel.font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf"

    m.sixthLabel = m.top.findNode("sixthLabel")
    m.sixthLabel.font.size = 20
    m.sixthLabel.color = "#ffffff"
    m.sixthLabel.font.uri = "pkg:/fonts/Inter-Medium.ttf"

end function
```

welcome_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<component name="welcome_screen" extends="Group"> 
<script type="text/brightscript" uri="pkg:/components/screens/welcome_screen.brs" />
    <children>
    <Group>
    <Poster id="background" uri="pkg:/images/welcome.png" width="1280" height="720">
    <Rectangle 
        id="overlay" 
        width="1280" 
        height="720"
        color="#0007" 
        opacity=".5"
    />
    <Label id="firstLabel" 
        text="The art of digital"
        height="21"
        width="160"
        translation = "[ 675, 191 ]"
    />
    <Label id="secondLabel" 
        text="Experience the cutting edge of art."
        height="151"
        width="252"
        translation = "[ 675, 244 ]"
        wrap="true"
    />
    <Label id="thirdLabel" 
        text="Download our mobile app"
        height="70"
        width="160"
        translation = "[ 951, 191 ]"
        wrap="true"
    />
    <Label id="fourthLabel" 
        text="Scan QR Code"
        height="21"
        width="150"
        translation = "[ 951, 261 ]"
    />
    <Poster 
        id = "qrcode" 
        uri = "API-result" 
        height="210"
        width="210"
        translation = "[ 951, 287 ]" 
    />
    <Label 
        id="fifthLabel" 
        text="or enter code to pair device"
        height="21"
        width="200"
        translation = "[ 951, 511 ]"
    />
    <Label 
        id="sixthLabel" 
        text="API-result"
        height="21"
        width="200"
        translation = "[ 951, 530 ]"
    />
    </Poster>
    </Group>
    </children>
</component>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make API calls in BrightScript is used `roUrlTransfer`. It's designed to be used only in the `main` thread or in [Task](https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/scenegraph/control-nodes/task.md) threads. In other words, there is no possibility to create that object directly in the `welcome_screen` component.
To achieve your goal you would need to create a separate Task, make a request there, parse it, and then return a response to the `welcome_screen`. Here is a Task example:
https://github.com/rokudev/samples/tree/master/ux%20components/control/TaskExample

Documentation regarding `roUrlTransfer` interface: https://developer.roku.com/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifurltransfer.md

Also, I think it will be useful to review those samples to get a better understanding of how things work on Roku: https://github.com/rokudev/samples